# MapStuct strategy update field list

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have two class entity parent-child:

```
public class Parent {
  private String name;
  private List<Child> children;
}
public class Child {
  private String name;
}
```

And I need to have TWO mapper update methods, one completely replaces the collection, the other adds new elements to it.

```
@Mapper(
    componentModel = "spring",
    uses = {ChildMapper.class})
public interface ParentMapper {
Parent updateParent(ParentTo to, @MappingTarget Parent parent); //works correctly

Parent updateParentAddChild(ParentTo to, @MappingTarget Parent parent); //it does not work correctly
}
```

By default, when updating, the mapper replaces all entities in the collection.

How is it more correct to implement an entity update in the mapper with the addition of elements to the sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both working correctly, but they did the same thing.
You changed only the name, and this is the reason why the implementation will remain the same.

"Replace completely" is the common behavior. So in order to completely replaces the collection, it's ok what you already did.

```
Parent updateParent(ParentTo to, @MappingTarget Parent parent);
```

Instead, if you need a specific implementation (like updating the collection by adding new elements), you can simply create a method with your custom implementation:

```
@Mapping(target = "children", expression = "java(updateChildrenList(to, parent))")
Parent updateParentAddChild(ParentTo to, @MappingTarget Parent parent);

default List<Child> updateChildrenList(ParentTo to, Parent parent) {

    //add here your custom mapping implementation

}
```

If you need, there is also a CollectionMappingStrategy called ADDER_PREFERRED that can be applied to override the default behaviour.

You can find more info about that on Baeldung: [collections-mapping-strategies](https://www.baeldung.com/java-mapstruct-mapping-collections#collections-mapping-strategies)